# How to query data from a pivot table and display it using blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am trying to query data from my pivot table and display it on my view

My View

```
@foreach ($catalog_downloads as $catalog_download)
<td>
    
    <?php $frequencies = $catalog_download->export_frequencies()->get(); ?> 
    
    {{{ $frequencies }}}

</td>
@endforeach
```

When I do `{{{ $frequencies }}}` I got this :

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Semi Annual","created_at":"2015-01-14 15:44:59","updated_at":"2015-01-14 15:44:59","pivot":{"catalog_download_id":104,"export_frequency_id":1}},{"id":2,"name":"Quaterly","created_at":"2015-01-14 15:45:06","updated_at":"2015-01-14 15:45:06","pivot":{"catalog_download_id":104,"export_frequency_id":2}},{"id":3,"name":"Monthly","created_at":"2015-01-14 15:45:13","updated_at":"2015-01-14 15:45:13","pivot":{"catalog_download_id":104,"export_frequency_id":3}}]
```

But I don't want that. I want only the **name**.
So I did this `{{{ $frequencies->name or '' }}}` and now nothing come up at all. :(

#### More details

Here is how I define my relation.

```
public function export_frequencies(){ 
        return $this->belongsToMany('ExportFrequency','export_frequency_catalog_download','catalog_download_id','export_frequency_id');
        
    }
```

[image]

Can someone tell me what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Laravel only selects the two foreign key from the pivot table. To change that add `withPivot` to your relationship definition:

```
public function export_frequencies(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Frequency')->withPivot('name');
});
```

Then you can access it through the `pivot` object:

```
@foreach($frequencies as $frequency)
    {{ $frequency->pivot->name }}
@endforeach
```

### Edit

I guess I've been confused by your question title. If you just want to display data from `ExportFrequency` you don't need `withPivot` and you can simply do this:

```
@foreach($frequencies as $frequency)
    {{ $frequency->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Will do that now. Thanks @lukasgeiter

Comment: I added `->withPivot('name');` to the end of what I have, and now I got this error : [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/withPivot.JPG)

Comment: But your pivot table has a `name` column? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: My pivot only have 3 ids: id, catalog_download_id, and export_frequency_id. No `name` column - sorry if I confused you, but in `export_frequecies` table have `name` column, and I want to grab that.

Comment: I saw, thanks for updating it. I'm trying it now. In the mean time, I included more detail to my post, feel free to go take a look.

Comment: I think I got the same error message, but closer `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'export_frequency_catalog_download.name'`

Comment: Have you removed `withPivot()`?

Comment: I did that and nothing come up ! nothing seem to take effect. No data is displaying.

Comment: Yep ;) "[...] you don't need withPivot [...]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69219/discussion-between-evoque2015-and-lukasgeiter).